# How to insert text from a text file into a Label Control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

Could someone demonstrate how to insert text from a text file e.g. test.txt into a Label control on a visual C# form please

Answer (score 8):

You leave much to the imagination as to where you currently are with this and from which point you need help, but in the simplest form, try this:

```
theLabel.Text = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
label.Text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
```

[File.ReadAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The answers for the question are useful so far.

Also you are considering this for WinForms as far as I understood from the tags.

If you would like to do any kind of action like this on Web Forms, you should consider that the text from the file goes without any encoding to label control. So, any kind of JavaScript code can be injected.

Always HtmlEncode your text;

```
var pathToFile = Server.MapPath("~/poo.txt");
lblPoo.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(File.ReadAllText(pathToFile));
```